# Quicksort Q: Finitely many distinct keys

Tags: java, c++, sorting, computer-science, quicksort

Need to show that a quicksort with a special partitioning, where an array gets partitioned into 3 parts (< than 3 pivot, = to pivot, > than pivot) and a special array of size N where only 7 distinct keys are possible can be sorted in O(N).

So, I suppose we can assume the pivot is being chosen somewhere in the middle (otherwise we could have something like [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, .....] and that should take O(N^2)).

Here is what I am thinking:
Suppose we did the first partitioning.  Now we move to the recursive step 2. Suppose we only focus on the right partition. Since every element here is greater than the pivot, and there were only 7 distinct keys, the number of distinct keys in this partition is strictly less than 7. This implies that after 7 iterations of the algorithm, all elements in the left and right sub-sub-...-partitions should be the same.

Now, I can see how this would be O(N) if the algorithms stopped recurring on a constant array, but my understanding is that it doesn't.  Please clarify this if its not the case.

So what's going on here?

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Hint: What is the **worst-case** performance for sorting the array `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, ...]`?

Comment: if we assume pivot selection at the middle O(NlgN). If pivot is the first entry, then O(N^2)

Comment: @user96454 Incorrect. In the **worst case**, how many recursive calls will you need?

Comment: If you have only 7 distinct keys ... do you need to stick with quick sort? Bucket, counting our radix sort could be your friends.

Comment: I'm not sure why its incorrect. In the **worst case**, 1 is out first pivot so no changes happen, 2 is our second pivot - no changes, 3 is the 3rd pivot - no changes...all the way until the Nth element. That is O(N^2) recursive calls.

Comment: @Hcorg when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quicksort algorithm looks like this:

```
quicksort(A, lo, hi):
  if lo < hi:
    p := partition(A, lo, hi)
    quicksort(A, lo, p - 1)
    quicksort(A, p + 1, hi)
```

We have a special partition that is 3-way, so let's say it returns the equal range for whatever pivot it picks and we just need to go below and above that:

```
quicksort(A, lo, hi):
  if lo < hi:
    p1, p2 := 3-way-partition(A, lo, hi)
    quicksort(A, lo, p1 - 1) // (1)
    quicksort(A, p2 + 1, hi) // (2)
```

Now, consider the *very worst* case. We have an array that looks like `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,6,6,6...]` and our pivot selection algorithm is as dumb as possible: it picks the pivots in strictly increasing order. In this case, the first recursive call (`(1)` above) will always do nothing because there will be nothing smaller than the pivot. So we're only ever dealing with one single recursive call - of size `N - 1`.

Each recursive call reduces the problem size by one, until the 7th recursive call (which will pick the `6` pivot) - that one completes the sort. This is the key step in only having 7 distinct keys - you only need at most 7 calls. Each of those 7 calls iterates the entire array... that's `O(7N) == O(N)`. More generally, if there are only `k` distinct keys, you can say that the worst case is `O(kN)` from the same argument.

Comment: I have a couple questions. First, this is exactly what I had in mind when I said O(N^2), but from what you are describing the algorithm stops when it hits 6. My understanding was that quicksort my default doesn't have a mechanism for "detecting" a sorted array, and it will continue breaking the problem down to its smallest size. This is why I didn't assume the algorithm would stop when `6` was picked as a pivot.

Comment: @user96454 Well, given an array that only consists of `6`s, what would `3-way-partition` do?

Comment: Ahh, I just got the fact that you are not calling quicksort on the middle partitions, which [6, 6, 6, .....] would surely be. Makes sense, i was calling quicksort on all 3 parts of a partition